# there is not enough memory to perform the requested operation please increase xmx

Tags: windows, android-studio, 32-bit

After clicking on this shutdown..the Android studio is not opening now?
I am using 32 bit window with 4GB RAM.. can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named gradle.properties in

`C:\Users\<username>\.gradle`

Then, add the line in it:

`org.gradle.daemon=true`

This worked for me. You can try it.

Edit:-
If the above doesn't work, then try removing the caches folder from

`C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudio<version_number>\system`